# How can I check if a command line argument is a directory in C

Tags: c

How do I check if an argument in the command line is a directory and if it is a directory, how can I count all the file and sub directory it has?

Comment: That's not really a single question. The answer to the last part is way larger than the answer to the first. Please just ask a single question in each question. That's why they're called "questions".

Comment: What platform? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

In POSIX, you can use [`stat()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat) to check if a filename refers to a file or directory.